# Laravel 4 DomPDF - PHP not Streaming Issues

Tags: laravel-4, dompdf, laravel-4.2

I am using laravel 4 with DOMPDF to display an PDF. While i am clicking PDF it will display like below:

```
%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R /F2 9 0 R >> /XObject << /I1 10 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 841.890 595.280] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text /ImageC ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (DOMPDF) /CreationDate (D:20160823103816+00'00') /ModDate (D:20160823103816+00'00') >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 2558 >> stream x��[�n7}�W�1����v$�me%�29+$A�ز��d9F� �~�~j�3�K��l�L`b�����u�{�~;B�����`�)�$�XR��=���Ο��;"X�k��/�N7�E1L�e����¡��~���������w�������<>��/�����}��|���4�,������<�������緟����O�O7'�������?��d���s�WJ�9����1;$�4����:[-PJ/x   � �����z�bԇY,��,_8�]-..���*��r��b5��ju�y}y�n���=Z/oV� �����+�U?~��U�#�d���TH��zq}�������f��"!6L��߻�� $��J�\����\�/����ƺ��  0t���U���7v|~�$��N���������p8�i��<�>4�¥�� ��D¨�-�����C(*�e��mqFbn+���db!��5R4n�w�,�C��-���hSN1������|���    ��b*m��1���[$�����3���)9����N��a�U�y��Փ��[ ���g��|���y �ID�p<��� n�w��[)LU펝� S��z6o�yg���-��{���0�k�I���S��[�������;���5��&��؈��3�E�Y�*o k�� �0�X��6��yg���a�%n;��bw�鼤�@>T#/�X����ް��M�1D��<�E�Y�*o([+z�Zr��>KoPc�yp�ܳ@U��4>�[�F$��`��$��x��j�%5��� �[�X�0�A�y{��;T���auo��Bnf���;T�m�"���ƧkE������3��y�wc�f������+ZJ��'��A+�E�Y�*w {�*=c&'��,�Aav���!��"�,P����+��t�5e���4��y�o�w_>y�c ��$w��#֧҆Ns�n�{h�}D�8�{m)XZVmV�2��c7�'�6ԥQIo�*&t%ͭ�D눒fu�N�衒���.EA4�0 ��HD�g�u=�\�X��ZDs��P4����n��L��g����`    �t�����Q�^�����́{�E3�k|�w'u9���h�CxwRw.�L!G��Ļ����R����́w�E3»����L�yg�Z4�!�;�;��� 9j�&�Fl��S�ҝ��\ G����K�r��nz͑̑w�E2y$�8�N�&��,��g�Z$s�;����n�=S2�y��|@�x��x�$s��j�̇������r��M�;�\���Z�Jw&�\ G����K� �L2�s��n�gI��=�"���餐�J7�)�#�,P�d>�нҝy��9J��^2yK��f�{�t=�\��g�&%sT��i՝d. �y��)�U��N�?�V�`�X�������1%i|L ��U��'���2��ih9,a�rF����pCCww�v/7ѩ�N�W P��9@��W���bx:\wU��2Aе0�2,�544wk���D"�/���[2(�C����1ByK����PA��`�C��?��h�[2(/�����*ByK�=��U�eqt��K�%ByK��K  ����y���%��j�'���FP�҇ a�$��>ByK�g����$��%��cxm�&���,}�09�መ\]�w#��dp~�-±I,?�F,oɰ�|�����2@KJ�"��T��8�vr��$��%��͆�3X2�~,1�B����zS�j`c�����^.�}����ޣ�ً���K��p8�9�܌��ߟ����COc�������oX��juw�ipA�Y5%`jqR���=��Xp���&�[�B��`el2��^nG?��YZ!s�����_���tU6��m�֍ n&OhgI���`�k;�)��˦ �Sm�4�쵇������*> endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2 /BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 10 0 obj << /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 64 /Height 64 /Filter /FlateDecode /DecodeParms << /Predictor 15 /Colors 3 /Columns 64 /BitsPerComponent 8>> /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /BitsPerComponent 8 /Length 929>> stream h�՚�n�@����T�R�#���.�"Z!�����P���\!W[M�.����]�,��*@ș��������3����6��n�O�M]�#����|֯/�����D4�I��Ǉ�pEQ�$UUM\UU�e�l6�O~C�8��|��DD��>�cD�>5��������k�~�gߴZ ���bQŤ4QY���g��$��"*�b�X�Z�ડ,����#'I�N��O b����nD?Q�睑��Q����j+��z�6Xfp�����{��3w@#��k�!��<�<�TU�~�����r��R�y�{���`/1˲p9��k�8��~��slpW?��4ǽ��3VI܂�LY� �ӮY���"��|���@p�>9=,k[�;� u]ߝsl�M��%p����fE��^`\�%=��["�e^b�-�|CHcS[뺶��,��õ��O�n�K�Tv����}a�5/��N �M���x�7    "�y\��� ��������L(Dt:��,��wQ�$�T����C���(���cs�    �3����9�vƒ�R���}�6��XL�R�t:%Ib��!v�2��������M���@峷����1H�V_(��C�NS�����\sV�ՀS���a����i��~i`��b�c��0D�����N8�I��k}�Ӷ�����}����Y��Ŵ�ug|_�}��������>���M��L��b9/�z�k��Ͼ�ͼ�-����c��i����;B�{�#�֌�O������`�����*�BvΑ����k}���%�9kǪ���yi>������i�N�z���������f�a�O���`�ݎg�/��� endstream endobj xref 0 11 0000000000 65535 f 0000000008 00000 n 0000000073 00000 n 0000000119 00000 n 0000000310 00000 n 0000000347 00000 n 0000000461 00000 n 0000000524 00000 n 0000003155 00000 n 0000003262 00000 n 0000003374 00000 n trailer << /Size 11 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref
```

How to solve this issues. Please Help Me. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's the source of the PDF. So laravel-dompdf is streaming the PDF, it's just that the browser doesn't know how to handle it because the mime type is incorrect. To supply an answer we'll need more details about your usage of the library.

Comment: You can use dompdf library for this. Add "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*", to your composer.json file and update your composer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how to convert data into pdf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343361/convertise-data-in-pdf-in-laravel-5-3/39345992#39345992). Try this code in to generate pdf. Dont forget to use dompdf library.