# Convertise Data in Pdf in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3

I want to convert data in pdf using laravel 5.3. I have tried using fpdf. but i did not get any success. how to convert data in pdf using laravel 5.3.

Comment: Added some code. What your tried. "i did not get any success" means got any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which which I used in my ReportsController and will help you to convert your data into pdf

```
public function getDownloadPDF($id){

        $objReports=Walkthrough::find($id);
        $objReports=DB::table('walkthroughs')
                    ->join('users','users.id','=','walkthroughs.user_id')
                    ->select('users.first_name as FirstName','users.last_name as LastName','walkthroughs.start_date as StartDate','walkthroughs.end_date as EndDate','walkthroughs.unit as Unit','walkthroughs.reminder_date as ReminderDate','walkthroughs.address')
                    ->where('walkthroughs.id','=',$id)
                    ->first();

         $view = \View::make('pdf.admin_reports',
         compact('objReports'))->render(); 

        $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($view);
        $pdf_name = date('YmdHis').$id. '.pdf';
        $pdf->save(public_path('assets/pdf/' . $pdf_name));

         return Redirect::to('/assets/pdf/'.$pdf_name);
}
```

So similarly you can take data from database and convert it to pdf. 
Also use following code to render your view

```
$view = \View::make('pdf.walkthroughDetail',
                            compact('walkthrough','completed_time','selectedRoomTags',
                            'items','selectedTags','housemates','landlords',
                            'inspector_info','completed_time'))->render(); 

        $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($view);
        $pdf_name = date('Ymdhis') . '.pdf';
        $pdf->save(public_path('assets/pdf/' . $pdf_name));
```

In this case your view pdf.walkthroughDetail is converted into pdf file.

Comment: i want to convert record of table in pdf using laravel 5.3. how to use above mentioned code in controller.shall i retrieve the data in view. and how to call in controller.do i need to download any file for converting data in pdf

Comment: check view rendering code , which I edited in answer. You just need to write your view such that you want to see your pdf, because at the end your view will going to convert into pdf.

Comment: Let me know if you facing any issue here.